# What is the purpose to define different moments on a distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the purpose to define different moments on a distribution?

The first moment is the expectation value of a function, what about the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second moment is a close relative of the variance, a very important measure of variability. More precisely, $\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$.

Higher moments tend to be of much less importance than the first two.